# Applying matlab histogram values to matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab, histogram

This might be simple and I apologize if it is so.

In matlab I have a double precision matrix which can theoretically have the range of +/- infinity.

I would to use the histogram function in matlab to change the values of the matrix.

For instance, if data elements fall within histogram bin 1 then I would like to assign the value of 1 to this and all of its instances.

Is there a quick and cheap way of doing this?

I have tried lookuptables etc but matlabs LUT is a pain.

Thank you for looking at my question

Answer (score 2):

I think I just cracked it ...

Make a new function out of hist and after edges in the m file add this line:

```
[~,my_labels] = histc(y,edges,1);
```

and my_labels will contain your matrix with the histogram values instead of the actual values.

Comment: Yep. Second output of `histc` is the way to go